# Line break in Prometheus' HTML Alert / Rule view

Tags: regex, prometheus, line-breaks, prometheus-alertmanager

I have several Prometheus alerting rules which are quite long. In my editor I manage to add line breaks to the rules' expressions (see line expr) with a `|` at the beginning:

```
- alert: IF_Critical
  annotations:
    description: The service on {{ $labels.route }} at {{ $labels.application }}is critical and has not received any timestamp in the last 60 minutes.
    summary: Service State is critical.
  expr: |
    (
      (camel_route_last_exchange_failure_timestamp > camel_route_last_exchange_completed_timestamp
    or
      camel_route_up == 0)
    or
     (time() - round(camel_route_last_exchange_completed_timestamp/1000) > 3600
    and
    (
      time() - round(camel_route_last_exchange_failure_timestamp/1000) > 3600
    and
      round(camel_route_last_exchange_failure_timestamp/1000) != 0
    ))
```

However, when looking at Prometheus' HTML overview of the Rules and Alerts, those line breaks disappear and instead the expression is just one really long line. See the following picture:

[Prometheus HTML long rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIKbT.png)

Therefore, the following questions:

1. Is it possible to apply visible line breaks also in the HTML overview?
2. Moreover, when having a regex for a Prometheus rule e.g. `route=~"ABC1|DEF1|GHI1|...ABC9|DEF9|GHI9|"` which is also really long. Is it possible to break within this regular expression?

For 2 I have already tried either `\` (one backslash) or `\\` (two backslashs) before adding a line break with enter but then promtool always says "unknown escape sequence" or "unterminated quoted string"

Appreciate your help. Hope it is clear so far.

Thanks in advance!